# AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining multiple dataframes and I am calculating the output by multiplying two columns from two diff dataframes and dividing it with a column belonging to another dataframe. I get grouping sequence expression is empty error and no_order is not an aggregate function. What's wrong with the code?

```
df = df1.join(df2,df2["code"] == df1["code"],how = 'left')\
.join(df3, df3["id"] == df1["id"],how = 'left')\
.join(df4, df4["id"] == df1["id"],how = 'left')\
.join(df5, df5["status"] == df1["status"],how='left')\
.withColumn("col1",concat(trim(df4.col1),trim(df3.col1)))\
.withColumn("col2",when(df1.col2 == 1,"S1").otherwise("S2"))\
.withColumn('Col3',((df1['Col3'].substr(6, 4))+df1['Col3']))\
.withColumn('Col4',(sum(df5["col4"] * df1["col4"])/df2['col4']))\
.groupby("col2","col2","col3","col1")\
.select("col2","col2","col3","col1")
```

> AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'select'.
> How can we stop the error. I cannot use max,avg or count functions

Answer (score 4):

You need to do an aggregation function after groupBy, like min, max, or gag to make more than one aggregation by the same key columns. Calling `groupBy` method returns a [RelationalGroupedDataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset)